# Access class property in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I’ve a typescript class which built like following

```
export default class myClass{

myns: any;

async initializing() {
…
this.myns = na.map(function (item) {
  return item["name"];
});

// here we have value 
console.log(this.myns);

}


search(test, input) {

input = input || "";
return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    let fuz= fuzzy.filter(input, this.myns);  //here I want to access myns but here it comes undefined in debug
    resolve(
      fuz.map(function (el) {
        return el.original;
      })
    );
});



}

}
```

I want to access `myns` inside the function `search` (in the function search is undfiend but inside init it have data)  search how can I do it ?

**not just `myns` is undefined `this` is undefined also**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `(resolve) => {` instead of `function (resolve) {` so it will bind this to the callback

EDIT:

Running this code worked for me:

```
class myClass {
  myns: any;

  async initializing() {
    this.myns = [{ name: 'test1' }, { name: 'test2' }].map(function (item) {
      return item["name"];
    });

    console.log(this.myns);
  }

  search(test, input) {
    input = input || "";

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      console.log('test');
      console.log(this.myns);

      resolve();
    });
  }
}

const test = new myClass();

test.initializing();
test.search('lala', 'lala2');
```

As expected the output was:

```
[ 'test1', 'test2' ]
test
[ 'test1', 'test2' ]
```

What is that fuzzy library you are using?